# Mixing UIView animation and CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uiview, cgaffinetransform

After reading some tutorials on animation, I was testing out a some stuff. I created a single view ARC project with storyboard. I added a UIImageView in the main view with center at (200, 200). I set the outlet correctly.

My idea was to animate the image (UIImageView *bug) moving to the left, then turning 180° to the right, moving back to the right, turning 180° to the left and so on.

This is my code

viewcontroller.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UIImageView *bug;
@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize bug;

#pragma mark - Animations


- (void)moveToLeft
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         NSLog(@"Animation 1");
                         bug.center = CGPointMake(100, 200);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [self turnToRight];
                     }
     ];       
}

-(void)turnToRight
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         NSLog(@"Animation 2");
                         bug.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [self moveToRight];
                     }
     ];
}

- (void)moveToRight
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         NSLog(@"Animation 3");
                         bug.center = CGPointMake(200, 200);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self turnToLeft];
                     }
     ];
}

-(void)turnToLeft
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         NSLog(@"Animation 4");

                             bug.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self moveToLeft];
                     }
     ];
}
```

Everything is ok until the second call to CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. The image goes left, rotates to right, goes right, and then the problem! The animations break and the bug move to the location of the first CGAffineTransformMakeRotation and then rotates to the left, and the steps repeats.

I've tried different approach, but it seems that every consequent call to CGAffineTransform don't take into account the new position of the UIImageView and perform the transformation always in the first location it was called. I've checked a lot of examples and the code seems correct, I just don't understand why mixing CGAffineTransformMakeRotation with regular animation is causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `UIViewAnimation`**`Option`**`CurveEaseInOut` instead of `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut`. They are from different enums and when using block animations always use those with **`Option`** in name.
The value you specified was `UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews`, which may cause the relocation.

This is the only problem I found in your code. If this is not the solution, then you found a bug :)